# Is there any more fast\efficient way to run 255 threads like this? CPP

Tags: c++, multithreading

I ran 255 threads that trying to connect to some server.
But its took alot of timr (10 seconds) till the all threads are done.
If some thread succeed to connect, then the SOCKET I sent by ref, will be filled with the id of that server.

```
void TryConnect(int octet, SOCKET& soc_returned)
{
    Client temp_client;
    int first_of_last_octet = getway.find_last_of('.') + 1;
    getway = getway.replace(first_of_last_octet, 3, std::to_string(octet));
    try
    {
        temp_client.GetInfo(getway.c_str(), S_PORT);
        temp_client.CreateSocket();
        temp_client.Connect();
        soc_returned = temp_client.socket_id;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << octet << std::endl;
    }
}

void TryConnectOnSubnet(std::string getway)
{
    std::vector<std::thread*> threads;
    SOCKET soc_returned;
    for (int i = 1; i < 254; i++)
    {
        std::thread* t = new std::thread(&Client::TryConnect, this, i, std::ref(soc_returned));
        threads.push_back(t);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 253; i++)
    {
        threads[i]->join();
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I dont understand why does it tool too long to do this thing. somebody have any idea?
BTW, I noticed I didnt activate the `delete` on this threads.

Comment: Did you already try what in special takes too long? I mean did you do some time measurement?

Comment: Yes. the "connect" function. it is a normal connect of C threads. I just warped it.

Comment: How much time does it take to run 1 Connect in 1 thread? What about 2 Connect in 2 threads?

Comment: maybe you could use your threads for more than one connection test? I mean you have a defined number of processes you can handle, when you give them more work you could remove your overhead to create a lot of them.

Comment: You need to synchronise modifications of `soc_returned`, and sharing `getway` between threads is not a good idea if you're going to modify it.

Comment: Why do you need a lot of threads?  I suggest you use 2 threads, profile.  Use 3 threads, profile. Use 4 threads, then profile.  I would expect there is a point where adding more threads actually slows down the performance of the overall program.  Remember that each thread has creation and maintenance overhead.  Also, there is no guarantee that the OS will assign each thread to a separate core; the could all be time-sliced on the same core.

Answer (score 4):

Threads are expensive to create in general. One can take up to 8MB of RAM. They have big overhead. The most accepted approach for network programming is some sort of asynchronous demultiplexing using very few threads.

Take a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html and get some insights. I recommend you to study it, since the ISO commitee is already doing a Technical Specification in which the standard networking library will be based, based on Asio.

What you want if you want to run many things in parallel that are I/O bound, is a callback-based chaining flow, coroutines or futures + continuations, with one or very few threads.

This is not an easy topic but will give you a lot of insights on the right way to do it. I recommend you to take a look at the examples. Understanding the library takes some time.

Comment: Do you think it will help with the timing? If connect takes 1/25th of a second I think the time result will be same

Comment: I dont want to use outside libraries. I want to learn ebough to know how to build that libraries.

Comment: @FeQlw the idea would be the same: make your code asynchronous without using 255 threads, but you are going to have a bad time doing that with plain BSD-style sockets.

Comment: @Alek86 I am not sure I understand your question, but if the OS does the connect asynchronously (as in async_connect), a handful of connects will be sent almost instantly (the max is set by the OS), so that should make things as concurrent as possible at the OS level, but you won't have the overhead of creating 255 software threads that take time, and map to hardware threads, so there are context switches. All in all, I think that it just would be faster, especially because of the removal of thread creation and context switch overhead.

Comment: @GermánDiago, what I meant is: your proposal is good, it's always better to use async rather than N threads. But I'm not sure if changing approach would fix the timing issue in the main question (I can be wrong).

Comment: @Alek86 that would require measuring where the overhead is: you have processing and I/O + thread creation. If the processing is very heavy, thread creation is not a big part. Otherwise, it could become a problem. But I am not in a position even to suspect where the bottleneck is without measuring, just some guess.

Comment: There is a very interesting phenomenon.  With process intensive threads, once you exceed the number of cores you have on your machine the more threads you run the slower your program runs.  Both throughput and latency suffer.

Comment: Thread-per-connection using blocking I/O is a viable model up to a point, then performance degrades for that approach too.  ASIO wins again.